# Mybatis ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

The error message goes like this below.

The error may exist in mappers/admin-mapper.xml 
The error may involve defaultParameterMap 
The error occurred while setting parameters 
Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character ] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
    <select id="selectCouponByDate" parameterType="String" resultType="Coupon">
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CPN_EXPIRED
    AS SELECT COUNT(COUPON_NAME) AS EXPIRED, COUPON_NAME
         FROM COUPON
        WHERE EXPDATE <![CDATA[<]]> SYSDATE
          AND ISUSED = 'N'
     GROUP BY COUPON_NAME;

    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CPN_USED
    AS SELECT COUNT(COUPON_NAME) AS USED, COUPON_NAME
         FROM COUPON
        WHERE ISUSED = 'Y'
     GROUP BY COUPON_NAME;
     
       SELECT C.COUPON_NAME
            , ISSUEDBY
            , LIMIT
            , COUNT(C.COUPON_NAME) AS ISSUED, EXPIRED, USED
         FROM COUPON C
    LEFT JOIN CPN_EXPIRED V1 ON(C.COUPON_NAME = V1.COUPON_NAME)
    LEFT JOIN CPN_USED V2 ON(C.COUPON_NAME = V2.COUPON_NAME)
    <choose>
        <when test="date == day">WHERE TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'yy-mm-dd') - TO_DATE(ISSUEDATE, 'yy-mm-dd') = 0</when>
        <when test="date == week">WHERE ISSUEDATE <![CDATA[>=]]> TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
                                  AND ISSUEDATE <![CDATA[<]]> TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 7</when>
        <otherwise>WHERE ISSUEDATE <![CDATA[>=]]> TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
                   AND ISSUEDATE <![CDATA[<]]> LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)</otherwise>
    </choose>
     GROUP BY C.COUPON_NAME, ISSUEDBY, LIMIT, EXPIRED, USED;
</select>
```

I can't find any typo.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end

Comment: Do you mean every semicolon or the semicolon at the very end?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support sending multiple statements in a single `execute()` call through JDBC. So unless MyBatis splits that into different statements, you will need to split this up manually and then remove each `;`

Comment: Just a note. Instead of `<![CDATA[<]]>` you can use `&lt;`. And... there's no need to escape `>` at all.

Comment: Split your mapper into three separated SQL statements, and problem solved. Oracle allows a single SQL per mapper.

Comment: You may also consider the `create view` as a part of the *installation* that is done *once* and remove them from the mapper. There is no reason to re-create the view *before each query* - this will also solve the problem.